# compress icons in the app without loosing the quality of the icons

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

i am developing one android project, in that project i have used icons with very quality, but because of that icons my app started **lagging.** So anyone can help with this issue?

PS : I want icons with same quality.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't provide any code!! Please add your code so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `Android Studio`
2. Navigate to the `drawable` folder where all your images which you have used in app are kept.
3. Android Studio provides a option where we can convert the images into **WebP** format where it decreases the size of image with less change in quality
4. Now right-click on the image,go to bottom where you can see the option called
   "Convert to WebP".
5. Click on it and it will ask you a confirmation regarding the encoding quality. Set as per your requirements or just leave as it is and click on OK Button.
6. Now a window opens where it will preview how much amount of image will get lost after compression and Before and After previews are shown there.
7. If you are satisfied, click on Finish Button.

Refer [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/webp) official documentation to know more about this feature.